# Preciso pegar os dados da url do navegador e passar esses dados para uma aplicação

Tags: javascript, java

Tenho uma aplicação java web start. E preciso fazer com que o navegador passe os parâmetros para essa aplicação. A função javascript está pegando os dados da url mas ainda não está passando para o outro programa.

Está muito difícil de fazer isso.

O código javascript está assim:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
 <html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">
        function OpenInNewTab(url) {
        var win = window.open(url,'_blank');
        win.focus();
        }
</script>   
</head>
<body onload = OpenInNewTab('launch.jnlp')>

<script>    

    function ObterParametroUrl(parametro){
        var parametros = window.location.search.substring(1).split("&");
            for(var i = 0; i < parametros.length; i++){
                var splitParametro = parametros[i].split("=");
                    if(splitParametro[0] == parametro){
                        return splitParametro[1];
                    } 
            }
    }

    var key_text1 = ObterParametroUrl('key_text1');
    var key_text2 = ObterParametroUrl('key_text2');

    if(key_text1 != ""){
        document.UserInput.print(key_text1,key_text2);
    }
</script>
<script>
    alert("text1 " + key_text1);
    alert("text2 " + key_text2);
</script>
</body >
```

A aplicação que recebe esse código está assim:

```
package applet;

import java.awt.*; 
import java.applet.*; 
import java.awt.event.*; 
import java.io.BufferedWriter; 
import java.io.FileWriter; 

  public class UserInput extends Applet implements ActionListener{ 

   TextField key_text1;
   TextField key_text2;
   TextField key_output; 
  Label key_label1,key_label2,key_label3; 
  Button key_button; 
  @Override
  public void start() {
      print(getParameter("string1"), getParameter("string2"));  
  }

  public void init(){ 
    // Create layout   

    setLayout(null); 
    // Add different components to the layout. 
    key_label1 = new Label("Entre password1: "); 
    key_label1.setBounds(20,20,100,20); 
    add(key_label1); 



    key_text1 = new TextField(5); 
    key_text1.setBounds(150,20,100,20); 
    add(key_text1); 

    key_label2 = new Label("Entre password2: "); 
    key_label2.setBounds(20,50,100,20); 
    add(key_label2); 

    key_text2 = new TextField(5); 
    key_text2.setBounds(150,50,100,20); 
    add(key_text2); 

    key_label3 = new Label("Os passwords sao: "); 
    key_label3.setBounds(20,80,130,20); 
    add(key_label3); 

    key_output = new TextField(5); 
    key_output.setBounds(150,80,100,20); 
    add(key_output); 

    key_button = new Button("Get keywords"); 
    key_button.setBounds(150,110,100,20); 
    add(key_button); 
    // Add action listener 
    key_button.addActionListener(this); 
    } 

  public  synchronized void print(String string1, String string2){
      this.key_text1.setText(string1);
      this.key_text2.setText(string2);
    }

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){ 
       // Test t = new Test(); 


        // String to get the user input texts 
        String str1= key_text1.getText(); 
        String str2= key_text2.getText(); 
        // Show output on the third text box 
        key_output.setText(str1+"--"+str2); 

        try{                
            // Create out put file 
            FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("output.txt",true); 
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream); 
            // Write to the file 
            out.write("\n"+str1+";"); 
            out.write("\t"+str2+";");            
            //out.write("\t"+str1+",");  
            // Flush the out put to the file 
            out.flush(); 
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        } 
    } 
}
```