# Sobre atualizar só uma tag html da página jsp

Tags: javascript, java

Eu tenho uma aplicação JApplet ela tem um botão que ao clicar ela pega o dado digitado no textfield e joga em uma url que é uma index.jsp e lá tem um getParameter que pega esse campo. O problema é que isso deve ser feito como ajax. O cara digita e aparece lá na página. Só que do jeito que está a aplicação está abrindo outra página e inserindo o valor nela. Alguém me ajuda?

```
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){ 

        // String to get the user input texts 
        //String str1 = (this.key_text1.getText());

      String nome = this.textfield.getText();
      System.out.println(nome);
      //aqui eu envio para a servlet.
      String path = "index.jsp";
      try{
          URL url = new URL(getDocumentBase(),path+"?nome="+nome);
          getAppletContext().showDocument(url);
          System.out.println(url);
      }catch(MalformedURLException e){
          showStatus("Não encontrado.");
      }
```

Comment: Essa pergunta não é duplicata dessa aqui? [Preciso pegar os dados da url do navegador e passar esses dados para uma aplicação](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/133565/28595)

Comment: "Essa pergunta não é duplicata dessa aqui?"

Comment: Não entendi seu comentario... O meu foi realmente uma pergunta.

Comment: @gonz Está usando div na parte do html ? Por que se sim,já fica mais fácil de resolver seu problema.

Comment: Estou usando sim uma div

Comment: Me explique mais